# Поле для ввода даты, как изменить значение по умолчанию на текст?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как изменить значение по умолчанию на текст ? например, в инпуте по умолчанию написано дд.мм.гггг хочу что бы вместо этого было написано: "Дата заезда".

```html
<input value="Дата заезда" type="date" />
```

Comment: Код весь покажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<input placeholder="Дата заезда" type="text" 
  onfocus="this.type='date'" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.type='text'}"/>
```